# Fade out script for preloader not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

I am a noob in HTML coding. I am just using some online available templates. I want to fade out the preloader in the below example. But it's not fading out. I tried replacing jQuery with $ in the script. It's still not working. Check the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sayan-das-the-animator/pen/jOExgQL) code! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Style CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: verdana;   
}
.title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.title h1{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;                     
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}
.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sayan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styl.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="title"><h1>SAYAN</h1></div>
    <div class="loader-wrapper">
        <span class="loader"><spam class="loader-inner"></span></span>
    </div>  
    <script>
        jQuery(window).on("load",function(){
            jQuery(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to `upvote` **all** helpfull answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work well if you don't forget to import the `JQuery` library:

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: verdana; 
}
.title{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.title h1{
 color: #000;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;                     
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}
.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sayan</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styl.css">

</head>
<body>
 <div class="title"><h1>SAYAN</h1></div>
 <div class="loader-wrapper">
  <span class="loader"><spam class="loader-inner"></span></span>
 </div>  
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(window).on("load",function(){
        $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please be aware next time of what is written in your console.